# list compare and replace on matching condition linq C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

```
public class UserValues
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int FieldId { get; set; }
    public string FieldValue { get; set; } 
}

public class LookupMeta
{
    public int FieldId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FieldValueId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I have kept this in 2 different lists after reading it from DB.

Now I want to compare both the list with

- `FieldId` ==  `FieldId`
- and `FieldValue` equals `Id`

then replace `FieldValue` from `uservalues` to `FieldValueId` from `lookupMeta`

```
UserValues
    .Where(x => LookupMeta.Any(y => 
        y.FieldId == x.FieldId && 
        y.FieldValueId.Equals(x.FieldValue)))
    .Select(x => x.FieldValue.Replace(x.FieldValue, ???))
```

I am looking at this link as well. I am struck [C# LINQ code for two list compare and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29272315/c-sharp-linq-code-for-two-list-compare-and-replace)

Is it good to have in List and doing like this or is there any other optimized way?

Comment: First of all `y.FieldValueId.Equals(x.FieldValue)` what is this supposed to do? You're comparing an `int` with a `string` value, this will always return `false`. Do you maybe wish to parse that string value to an int and compare with that?. Finally this way of doing it is definitely not the fastest way but imo first try and make this work for even a single record and only when you've got that logic working try and make it work with 2 lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment that has been left on [pwilcox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65259281/13268855) it seems like the OP is look for a solution where the unmatched rows are also included. That means instead of using inner join we are looking for a left outer join.

In the world of Linq this could be achieved via a combination of `GroupJoin`, `SelectMany` and `Select` operators.

In order to be able to join on two different columns we have to introduce an intermediate class to be able to tell the types of the `GroupJoin`. So, I have created the following class:

```cs
internal class IntermediateKey
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

We also have to define a comparer for this class to be able to find matching data:

```cs
internal class IntermediateKeyComparer : IEqualityComparer<IntermediateKey>
{
    public bool Equals(IntermediateKey x, IntermediateKey y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id && x.Value == y.Value;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IntermediateKey obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode() + obj.Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Please bear in mind that this implementation is quite simplified. The correct way to implement it is shown in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694508/how-to-use-the-iequalitycomparer).

Now can define our query as this:

```cs
var comparer = new IntermediateKeyComparer();
var result = userValues
    .GroupJoin(
        lookupMetas,
        uv => new IntermediateKey { Id = uv.FieldId, Value = uv.FieldValue },
        lm => new IntermediateKey  { Id =  lm.FieldId, Value = lm.Id.ToString() },
        (uv, lm) => new { Value = uv, Lookups = lm},
        comparer)
    .SelectMany(
        pair => pair.Lookups.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (paired, meta) => new { Value = paired.Value, Lookup = meta})
    .Select(res =>
    {
        res.Value.FieldValue = res.Lookup?.FieldValueId.ToString() ?? res.Value.FieldValue;
        return res.Value;
    });
```

- We defined that `userValues` should be left outer joined on `lookupMetas`

  - if `uv`'s `FieldId` is matches to `lm`'s `FieldId`
  - and if `uv`'s `FieldValue` is matches to `lm`'s `Id`'s string representation
- With the `SelectMany` we choose either the matching `LookupMeta` entity or `null`
- With the `Select` we update the `UserValue`'s `FieldValue` property only if there is a related `LookupMeta` otherwise we use its original value.

Now let's see how this works with some sample data:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var userValues = new List<UserValue>
    {
        new UserValue { FieldId = 1, FieldValue = "2"},
        new UserValue { FieldId = 2, FieldValue = "3"},
        new UserValue { FieldId = 4, FieldValue = "5"}
    };

    var lookupMetas = new List<LookupMeta>
    {
        new LookupMeta { FieldId = 1, Id = 2, FieldValueId = 20 },
        new LookupMeta { FieldId = 2, Id = 3, FieldValueId = 30 },
        new LookupMeta { FieldId = 3, Id = 4, FieldValueId = 40 },
    };

    var comparer = new IntermediateKeyComparer();
    var result = userValues
        .GroupJoin(
            lookupMetas,
            uv => new IntermediateKey { Id = uv.FieldId, Value = uv.FieldValue },
            lm => new IntermediateKey  { Id =  lm.FieldId, Value = lm.Id.ToString() },
            (uv, lm) => new { Value = uv, Lookups = lm},
            comparer)
        .SelectMany(
            pair => pair.Lookups.DefaultIfEmpty(),
            (x, meta) => new { Value = x.Value, Lookup = meta})
        .Select(res =>
        {
            res.Value.FieldValue = res.Lookup?.FieldValueId.ToString() ?? res.Value.FieldValue;
            return res.Value;
        });

    foreach (var maybeUpdatedUserValue in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{maybeUpdatedUserValue.FieldId}: {maybeUpdatedUserValue.FieldValue}");
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
1: 20
2: 30
4: 5
```

So, as you can see there is no matching `LookupMeta` for the last `UserValue` that's why its `FieldValue` remained intact.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response and for sharing this with an explanation so that I can learn as well.  I will try this and update this thread. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks so much. I can understand now and it's working.

Answer (score 2):

If I follow you correctly, then the `.Join()` method in LINQ may be of use to you.  Here I use it to accomplish what I think you're after.

```
UserValues
.Join(
    LookupMeta, 
    uv => new { uv.FieldId, uv.FieldValue },
    lm => new { lm.FieldId, lm.FieldValueId },
    (uv,lm) => {
        uv.FieldValue = lm.FieldValueId;
        return uv;
    }
);
```

The second and third lines in the method build anonymous objects from the source tables.  The values of these are matched to make a link.

The last line takes the joined entries as inputs and then gives your output.  In your case, I just return the UserValues entry.  But before I do I change its "FieldValue" property to the "FieldValueId" property of the LookupMeta entry.

You have some inconsistencies.  For instance, you talk about matching FieldValue to Id in the paragraph, but in the code you match FieldValue to FieldValueId.  Also, you use `==` in one comparison and `.Equals()` in the other.  No wrong answer here.  I just don't know your underlying objects.  So you may have to modify my code a bit to get what you want.  But it shows the general strategy that I hope will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and explanation. I got the query working but it's not giving me the correct answer. I am sorry if I didn't explain this earlier. UserValues has 1001 rows and lookup meta has 11 rows. After this, I want 1001 rows and replace the values wherever applicable in UserValues rows. Currently, it's excluding unmatched rows. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Rocky3151, @PeterCsala is correct in his answer.  You're looking for a left join in LINQ.  There's no direct left join method, but it can be done.  Seems he's accomplished it for you.

Comment: Something to consider though, is the possibility of doing your left join using SQL and afterwards importing it into C#.

Comment: @pwilox thanks for the suggestion. unfortunately, I have to write to dynamic SQL since the table name itself dynamic with unpivot to get one of the above list. it's complicated already. thanks for the response I will try the below approach and update the thread

Comment: @pwilox Thanks so much. I can understand now the entire thread and its working as expected. have a nice day.